# what does sysctl command execute in the terminal gives in Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, kernel

There are a lot of different variables I can change via `sysctl`. What are they? Is there a description of each variable somewhere?

There is much of information how to read\write varible, e.g.

- http://go2linux.garron.me/linux/2011/02/introduction-and-how-sysctl-linux-900/
- https://www.frozentux.net/ipsysctl-tutorial/chunkyhtml/howtosetvariables.html
- http://www.cs.unc.edu/~jeffay/dirt/FAQ/sysctl.html
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysctl.2.html
- ......

but there is no description of what they are

And I did read about `sysctl`, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysctl

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the kernel parameters that you can tune with sysctl are supposed to be documented in the linux kernel documentation:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/

However, I believe any kernel module can add its own sysctl tunables and external modules may not be documented. Additionally, some subsystem-specific parameters require reading source code.

The documentation is highly technical, but so is the operation you are doing by changing the parameter values for many parameters.

Comment: Thanks. There are more parameters on my linux than in that document. I guess they are coming from other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew's answer is good. The short version is that any modules you've added may add their own possible options.

However, passing the -a argument to sysctl will list all currently available values on your computer. This is clearly listed in the man pages for sysctl.

```
/sbin/sysctl -a
```

So, I guess that means RTFM would have answered this question too.